# Why count only one file

Tags: java

Create a synchronous multithreaded system to determine the total of all integers or fractions in three text files. If a stream is blocked, it must display its name as "LOCKED". Why count only one file (Thread with lock)? What the programs display:Thread-0 Locked!
Thread-2 Locked!
123.321 322099, it's only for one file

```
import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.util.concurrent.locks.*;
     
    public class Dispatcher {
     
        public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
     
            SumOfDigits sumOfDigits = new SumOfDigits();
     
            Thread thread = new Handler(new File("text.txt"), sumOfDigits);
            Thread thread2 = new Handler(new File("text2.txt"), sumOfDigits);
            Thread thread3 = new Handler(new File("text3.txt"), sumOfDigits);
            thread.start();
            thread2.start();
            thread3.start();
            thread.join();
            thread2.join();
            thread3.join();
     
            System.out.println(sumOfDigits.resultDouble + " " + sumOfDigits.resultInt);
        }
     
    }
     
     
    class SumOfDigits {
        double resultDouble;
        int resultInt;
        Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
     
        void sum(File file) {
            try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(file)) {
                int tempInt = 0;
                double tempDouble = 0;
                while (sc.hasNext()) {
                    String num = sc.next();
                    if (num.contains(".")) {
                        tempDouble += Double.parseDouble(num);
                    } else {
                        tempInt += Integer.parseInt(num);
                    }
                }
                boolean flag = lock.tryLock();
                if (flag) {
                    try {
                        resultDouble += tempDouble;
                        resultInt += tempInt;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    } finally {
                        lock.unlock();
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Locked!");
                }
     
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
     
    class Handler extends Thread {
        File file;
        SumOfDigits sumOfDigits;
     
        Handler(File file, SumOfDigits sumOfDigits) {
            this.file = file;
            this.sumOfDigits = sumOfDigits;
        }
     
        @Override
        public void run() {
            sumOfDigits.sum(file);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the point of creating the threads if all you are going to do is execute them synchronously? You might as well just use the single main execution thread and poll the `InputStream.available()` method to see if the stream is blocked.

Comment: @M.Gianota Looks like a homework assignment. Students are often asked to implement something using multiple threads to *learn* how to do that.

Comment: You should not change the question after answers have already been provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ReentrantLock` maintains a count of how many times it has been locked by the current thread. This count is decremented every time you call `unlock()` and the lock is release when the count reaches zero. Thus, to unlock the lock, you must call `unlock()` *as many times as you have called `lock()` **or** `tryLock()`*.

In your code, you call `tryLock()` and if it is successful, you then call `lock()` inside the try/finally block and then you call `unlock()` ***once***.

The first thread to lock the ReentrantLock will thus increment the count to two but only decrement the count to one, so the lock is never released. Therefore, no other thread can ever acquire the lock.

You should use `tryLock()` or `lock()` to the lock the `ReentrantLock`, not both.

Comment: I removed the lock, however why in the else block, does not output anything or should it be?

Comment: @VasilPetrovich Do you mean the else block that prints "Locked!"? According to your question, it is printing it for two of the three threads, just as one would expect if one thread is acquiring the lock and not releasing it, and the other two cannot acquire it; `tryLock()` would return false, and they would end up in the else block.

Comment: Yes, but for some reason does not display

Comment: @VasilPetrovich Your question says "What the programs display:Thread-0 Locked! Thread-2 Locked! 123.321 322099" so apparently it *does* display.

Comment: Once taken away the `lock` does not display

Comment: @VasilPetrovich I don't know how you've modified the code. You should ask a new question with your new code. You said, "I removed the lock," which is very strange. I'm not sure why you would remove it entirely rather than use it correctly. But then, it is not clear why you want to read the files in three different threads but then prevent them from running concurrently.

Comment: You said use either `lock` or `tryLock`, so I took `lock`, but then the `else` block doesn't work

Comment: @VasilPetrovich Oh, I thought you meant you removed the `ReentrantLock`. If you are releasing the lock (you have as many unlocks as locks), then it is possible the three threads are successfully sharing the lock, although that only seems likely if the files are quite short. If `tryLock()` is never returning false, then it is getting the lock in each case.

Comment: Made large files, but still do not get into the `else` block

Comment: Another question, if done through lock, then where should this block else be?`lock.lock();`
                `try {`
                    `resultDouble += tempDouble;`
                    `resultInt += tempInt;`
                `} catch (Exception e) { }`
                `finally {`
                   
                    `lock.unlock();
                }`

Comment: When you use `lock.lock()` there is no `else`. The call blocks until the lock becomes available.

Comment: That is, this condition cannot be met in this way: If the stream is blocked, it must display its name with the mark "LOCKED"

Comment: Then you should use either [`tryLock()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#tryLock()) or [`tryLock(long, TimeUnit)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#tryLock(long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)).